# Why is date returning nil after being parsed?

Tags: ios, nsdate

I have an app that currently fetches data from a web service and NSXML parses it into Core Data.  The  processing into Core Data.  I was missing an updatedAtData field and I asked the client to add it to their web service and they added it as a String.  This is what the method to parse the date does:

```
- (void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key forManagedObject:(NSManagedObject *)managedObject {

    if ([key isEqualToString:@"createdAt"] || [key isEqualToString:@"updatedAt"]) {
        NSDate *date = [self dateUsingStringFromAPI:value];
        [managedObject setValue:date forKey:key];
    } else {
        [managedObject setValue:value forKey:key];
    }
}
```

It runs fine up to here.  date is set by calling this method:

```
- (NSDate *)dateUsingStringFromAPI:(NSString *)dateString {
    [self initializeDateFormatter];
    dateString = [dateString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [dateString length]-5)];

    return [self.dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
}
```

But date never gets set, it returns nil.  I think it has to do with date formats, this is what the server returns:

```
1900-01-01T00:00:00
```

How do I fix my date string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date format should be

```
@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss"
```

assuming in year-month-date 'T' 12 hour (format) : minutes : seconds

So your code will go like this

```
     [self.dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss"];
    return [self.dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
}
```

Comment: ok but this date format is being returned by the server.  So i cant really change it.

Comment: Ok but is still not an NSDate format.  I can see it parsing the date string fine, but it doesnt convert it to an NSDate.

Comment: can you try by putting `NSString *dateString=@"1900-01-01T00:00:00"; NSDate *date=[self.dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];` and nslog it

Comment: He almost certainly wants 24-hour format -- "HH" instead of "hh".  The 12-hour format will never record a date in the PM.

Comment: I was getting null, so i changed it.  I now get this: `the unformatted date is 1900-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
the formatted date is 1900-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
`

Comment: Also consider setting the `locale` and `timeZone` as suggested in [Apple Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html).